# How to pause an OpenWhisk trigger

Tags: ibm-cloud, serverless, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

Following the documentation at https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/feeds.md

I have implemented a feed, and am capturing trigger `livecycleEvent` events. From the command line and from the console in IBM Cloud I am able to test the `CREATE` and `DELETE`.

What I have not been able to figure out is how to invoke the `PAUSE` and by extension the `UNPAUSE`.

`wsk trigger`

doesn't appear to have this option.

```js
function main (args) {
  let event = args.lifecycleEvent;
  let triggerName = args.triggerName;
  let authKey = args.authKey;


  if ('CREATE' === event) {
    console.log('Create event for trigger ', triggerName);
    ...
  } else if ('DELETE' === event) {
    console.log('Delete event for trigger ', triggerName);
    ...
  } else if ('PAUSE' === event) {
    console.log('Pause event for trigger ', triggerName);
    ...
  } else if ('UNPAUSE' === event) {
    ...
  } else {
    console.log('Check for other non lifecycle actions ');
  }


  return {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pause a trigger, just create and delete.
I feel you are thinking about `wsk rule disable`? (https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/triggers_rules.md)

Comment: Rules associate triggers with actions. What I have is a feed to a trigger. I did try to disable each of my rules, but none triggered a lifecycleEvent.